# How to change LLVMPass long opt command to a simple Command

Tags: llvm, llvm-clang

I am working on LLVM obfuscation project. I have written a llvm pass(lets say flow flattening pass) which i am running on source (test.c) with following command:

```
clang -emit-llvm test.c -c -o test.bc 
opt -load ../../.. LLVMFlattening.so -fla <test.bc>/dev/null
```

But i have seen that in O-LLVM project they achieved same thing using:

```
clang -emit-llvm test.c -c -o test.bc -mllvm -fla
```

Can someone tell me what is -mllvm here and how this changed to a simple command?

Answer (score 10):

`-mllvm` means `Additional arguments to forward to LLVM's option processing`. Therefore `-mllvm -fla` will pass `-fla` to the LLVM's option processing.

Clang and LLVM could run seperately. If you want clang to run llvm, and also have some options which you want llvm to aware. `-mllvm` is what you need.

Defautly, LLVM does not turn on all the transformation passes.  With `-fla`, LLVM will turn on the pass registered with command line argument `fla` by call function `RegisterPass<typename passName>`.

In your command line, opt's `-load` option is used to load plugin. If you want to use the simple command line as expect. Your pass need to be linked into the `opt` binary. This could be done in the following two ways:

1. (Without modify the existing LLVM source tree): Add your only pass's source  by adding `CMakeLists.txt` mentioned in this [link](http://llvm.org/docs/CMake.html#developing-llvm-passes-out-of-source)
2. Directly copy your pass source code folder into `<LLVM root>/lib/Transform` directory. And modify the `<LLVM root>/lib/Transform/CMakeLists.txt`, add `add_subdirectory(<pass name>)` line just like others.

Comment: but how they have added -fla (flag of flow flattening pass) with -mllvm. I do not want to use opt command to use my llvmPass

Comment: Where is llvm load path?

Comment: Sorry I have made a mistake, your pass code could be linked together with existing `opt` binary to make this done.  I have update my answer.

Comment: i tried this but no idea why it is not working. -mllvm is not turning on the -fla even after adding everything as suggested.

Comment: What is ` option processing`? Is it commandline arguments parser? Where can I know more about it? What additional arguments can be passed to it?

Answer (score 1):

I'm working on O-LLVM rencently, and came into the same problem. Here is my solution:

1.add `static cl::opt<bool> YOUR_FLA("fla", cl::init(false),"info...")` to `PassManagerBuilder.cpp`

2.add function `Pass *createYOUR_FLA(bool flag)` in your obfuscation pass source code

3.add `MPM.add(createYOUR_FLA(YOUR_FLA));` to function `populateModulePassManager` in `PassManagerBuilder.cpp`

The solution above works with my simple pass.

Comment: Hi, can you explain a little bit more, I want to pass arguments while loading my llvm pass