# How to Compile a c program in clang exactly the same as -O2 and -O3 of gcc

Tags: gcc, optimization, x86, clang, intrinsics

I want to evaluate an AVX2 program written in `c-intrinsics` using `gcc 5.4.0` and `clang 3.8` for compiling and using `perf` , `valgrind` and `IACA` for evaluating and analysis. I Exactly want the same optimization approach so I read this related question [clang optimization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15548023/clang-optimization-levels) and this page for gcc [optimization option for gcc](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Optimize-Options.html) but I still doubted .

`gcc -O2` and `gcc -O3` is my basis and want the same in clang since Clang do auto-vectorization in `-O2` and I don't want it when comparing the results with `gcc -O2` and want it when `-O3` is enabled in `gcc`. so the question is what command should I use in clang that is corresponded to these commands in gcc :

First:

compile :
`gcc -Wall -O2 -march=native -masm=intel  -c -S "%f"`

build: 
`gcc -Wall -O2 -mavx2  -o "%e"  "%f"`

Second:
compile :
`gcc -Wall -O3 -march=native -masm=intel  -c -S "%f"`

build: 
`gcc -Wall -O3 -mavx2  -o "%e"  "%f"`

Comment: If you're looking at compiler output for manually-vectorized code, the compiler usually can't auto-vectorize on top of that.  But sometimes compilers are dumb and will try to auto-vectorize your scalar cleanup loop or something.  So I'd suggest using `-O3 -fno-tree-vectorize` for both gcc and clang to disable auto-vectorization if that's what you want.

Comment: Thank you @PeterCordes, Should I use `-mllvm` option in clang?

Comment: IDK, I've never used `-mllvm`.  What does it do, and why do you think you maybe should use it?

Comment: @PeterCordes, The program is adding to matrix: so does it make any sense? I think we missed some thing. 
 gcc : `gcc -Wall -mavx2 -O3 -fno-tree-vectorize -o "%e"  "%f"` 
 The best time is 0.000100 sec in 10001 repetition for 448X448 matrix

clang : `clang "%f" -o "%e" -mavx2  -O3 -fno-tree-vectorize`
 The best time: 0.000067 sec in 10001 repetition for 448X448 matrix

Comment: I was reading an article that said "using clang with llvm", (maybe it means back-end and front-end, not using this option in command line)

Comment: Those times are pretty short.  Maybe put it in a repeat-loop?  IDK, look at the asm and / or perf counters and see if clang made a more efficient loop.  Also, if you're testing on a Haswell CPU, you should use `-march=haswell` to enable `-mtune=haswell` as well as `-mavx2`.  gcc's "generic" tuning still fails to optimize for things like macro-fusion on Intel and AMD CPUs.

Comment: I'm using a `skylake` CPU, I used `-march=native`. There is no change.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29946629/how-to-change-llvmpass-long-opt-command-to-a-simple-command says `-mllvm` is not useful on its own.  It's just for passing other low-level args to the llvm backend that clang doesn't handle natively.  I don't think know if clang supports any backends other than LLVM.

Comment: Ok, `-march=native` is good.  You left out the `-march=native` part for the command line options you said you benchmarked.

Comment: OK, peter when I use `perf` for the clang build file it records but throw an error to report it.
gcc build file report for cpu cycle is `1.17 │ 48:   vmovss 0x6c5080(%rdx,%rax,1),%xmm1
  0.61 │       vaddss 0x601080(%rdx,%rax,1),%xmm1,%xmm1
 40.94 │       vmovss %xmm1,0x789080(%rdx,%rax,1)
 36.37 │       add    $0x4,%rax
` What am I missing to record Clang build file data?

Comment: I thought you said you had manually vectorized the code with intrinsics.  Those are scalar instructions.  Anyway, I have no idea what you're doing wrong with `perf record` / `perf report`.

Comment: I work with vectorized but know I'm testing gcc and clan is scalar mode to see the performance

Comment: I use sudo perf -e "my needs" ./myBinaryfile and use sudo perf report to annotate the report. it works for `gcc` build file

Comment: -Os is the same as -O2

-Oz is based on -Os

    opt drops: -slp-vectorizer
    clang drops: -vectorize-loops

Comment: `-Os` also sets tuning options to favour small code-size.  It does things like using DIV instead of modular multiplicative inverses for division by constants.